# Regex for this date format: Day Date Month Year Time TimeZone

Tags: regex, string

I need a regex that will remove this kind of Date from a String, example:

Saturday 25 February 2017 15.37 EST

Comment: Is there a good reason for why you would want to do this in regex?

Comment: @SeanF I am doing some filtering of text/sentences and these dates are redundant and don't add to anything. As in, text from online news articles and whatnot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be a bit long. It'll match the dates with strange hours like 55:32 as well but I hope it does not matter at this case.

```
/(Monday|Tuesday|Wednesday|Thursday|Friday|Saturday)\s\d{1,2}\s(January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|Septemper|Obctober|November|December)\s\d{4}\s\d{1,2}\.\d{2}\sEST/
```

```js
var txt = document.getElementById('txt');

var reg = /(Monday|Tuesday|Wednesday|Thursday|Friday|Saturday)\s\d{1,2}\s(January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|Septemper|Obctober|November|December)\s\d{4}\s\d{1,2}\.\d{2}\sEST/g;

var newTxt = txt.innerHTML.replace(reg,"");
txt.innerHTML += "<p>"+newTxt+"</p>";
```

```html
<p id="txt">lets say that we've got some string with some date Saturday 25 February 2017 15.37 EST just here and also here Monday 5 December 2005 3.37 EST and here Friday 13 March 2018 12.12 EST as well.</p>
```